# Sumar valores de elementos html tipo output

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito sumar todos los output y que quede el total impreso abajo. Gracias.

```html
SURT 1
<form method="POST" oninput="U1.value=parseInt(valor1.value)- 
    parseInt(valor2.value)">
  <input type="number" id="valor1" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="valor2" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
  <output name="U1" for="valor1 valor2"> 
     </output>
</form>
SURT 2
<form method="POST" oninput="U2.value=parseInt(valor1.value)- 
    parseInt(valor2.value)">
  <input type="number" id="valor1" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="valor2" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
  <output name="U2" for="valor1 valor2"> 
    </output>
</form>
SURTIDOR 3
<form method="POST" oninput="U3.value=parseInt(valor1.value)- 
    parseInt(valor2.value)">
  <input type="number" id="valor1" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="valor2" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
  <output name="U3" for="valor1 valor2"> 
    </output>
</form>
CANTIDAD DE LITROS<br> ULTRA: <br>
```

Necesito sumar los output id `U1` `U2` `U3`...
Agradezco a todos su ayuda y me disculpo por exponer mal mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Estas limitado a usar solo html o usar javascript solo dentro de los atributos html?

Comment: Hola: puedo usar javascript dentro de html. asi sea en el body o head.

Comment: Intente usar document.getelementbyid para llamar los output pero no me funciono.

Comment: Es por que no tienen asignado ningún id

Comment: Me disculpo, no esta aclarado en el ejemplo del codigo. cuando probé document.getelementbyid si le agregé el atributo ID. nuevamente disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script defer> 
const u1 = document.querySelector('output[name="U1"]');
const u2 = document.querySelector('output[name="U2"]');
const u3 = document.querySelector('output[name="U3"]');
const resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');


function suma(){
 resultado.textContent = parseInt(u1.value) + parseInt(u2.value) + parseInt(u3.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta. pero no lo imprime en el html.

Comment: <button onclick="suma()">Suma<button>    
Agrega ese tag

Comment: ... codigo de ejemplo...  <script defer> 
const u1 = document.querySelector('output[name="U1"]');
const u2 = document.querySelector('output[name="U2"]');
const u3 = document.querySelector('output[name="U3"]');

function suma(){
 return parseInt(u1.value) + parseInt(u2.value) + parseInt(u3.value);
}
</script>
<button onclick="suma()">Suma</button>      tampoco lo imprime.

Comment: Tambien tene en cuenta que el valor del output puede cambiar en los input.

Comment: El resultado de la suma debe aparecer como el resultado del Output. (automatico)

Comment: agregale la funcion suma en el oninput Ej..
oninput = "U3.value=parseInt(valor1.value)- 
    parseInt(valor2.value);suma()"

Comment: Igual. no aparece la suma en el final.

Comment: Mira aqui esta hecho, miralo esa es la solucion
https://codepen.io/fanatico120/pen/gOwPmPJ

Comment: EXCELENTE. ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Comment: ¿Por que solo funciona en ese editor pero no en ningun otro?

Comment: bien. esa es exactamente la idea pero hacerlo funcionar en un html.  no en un editor.

Comment: Lo puedes descargar en la esquina esta un enlace de descarga, export -> zip y lo descomprimes

Answer (score 0):

En general no es una buena práctica tener ids repetidos. Tampoco veo la necesidad de utilizar muchos forms puesto que toda la funcionalidad es sobre el mismo formulario.

Existen muchas formas de realizar el objetivo, la que muestro busca todos los inputs y hace la suma de los pares correspondientes, colocando `0` cuando `parseInt` devuelve `NaN`.

```js
const u1 = document.querySelector('output[name="U1"]');
const u2 = document.querySelector('output[name="U2"]');
const u3 = document.querySelector('output[name="U3"]');
const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');


function suma() {
    const inputs = document.forms["form"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    u1.value = (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[0].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[0].value)) - (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[1].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[1].value));
    u2.value = (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[2].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[2].value)) - (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[3].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[3].value));
    u3.value = (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[4].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[4].value)) - (isNaN(parseInt(inputs[5].value)) ? 0 : parseInt(inputs[5].value));
    resultado.innerHTML = parseInt(u1.value) + parseInt(u2.value) + parseInt(u3.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="POST" oninput="suma();">
    <p>
        <p>SURT 1</p>
        <input type="number" id="valor1" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
        <input type="number" id="valor2" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
        <output name="U1" for="valor1 valor2"></output>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p>SURT 2</p>
        <input type="number" id="valor3" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
        <input type="number" id="valor4" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
        <output name="U2" for="valor1 valor2"></output>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p>SURTIDOR 3</p>
        <input type="number" id="valor5" placeholder="Ultra Nuevo" value=""> -
        <input type="number" id="valor6" placeholder="Ultra Anterior" value=""> =
        <output name="U3" for="valor1 valor2"></output>
    </p>
    <p>
</form>
CANTIDAD DE LITROS<br> ULTRA: <br><span id="resultado"></span>
```

Comment: Hola agradezco tu respuesta. pero esa salida no resuelve el objetivo.